# Cross-platform command line script (e.g. .bat and .sh)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cross-platform

I noticed that Windows 7 enables to execute .sh files as if they were .bat files. That got me wondering whether it is possible to write a .sh file such that it can be executed in Windows *and* Linux (let's say bash).

The first thing that comes to my mind is to fabricate an if-statement such that Windows and Ubuntu can deal with it and jump into the according block to execute plattform-specific commands. **How could this be done?**

*Note:* I know this is not good practice. I also know that scripting languages like Python are far better suited to solve this problem than a mixed-syntax command line script would be. I'm just curious...

Comment: You may find https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh interesting

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use this:

```
rem(){ :;};rem '
@goto b
';echo sh;exit
:b
@echo batch
```

It's valid shell script and batch, and will execute different blocks depending on how it's run.

Modify the `echo` and `@echo` lines to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. I'd be interested, though, if there are other ways.

Comment: You can modify the first line to `@rem(){ :;};@rem '` to make this line silent on Windows. A similar idea is presented here https://danq.me/2022/06/13/bash-batch/