# How to update .config item value in pre-build event

Tags: c#, bash, visual-studio, pre-build-event

I have an app.config file that (initially) looks like this:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="MySetting" value="[MySetting]" />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I need a way to update '[MySetting]' value in pre-build event without copying another .config file into this one. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use powershell script that will replace the 'templates' with desired values.

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$DIR\app.template.config").Replace("[MySetting]", $MySettingValue) | Set-Content "$DIR\app.config"
```

**Update**

If you want to mix build environments - linux and windows, make sure that you will have a script that either run on both systems (i.e. python) or use powershell or (xor ^_^) sed but make it runnable from both systems using cmd label that is ignored on linux - for more info see i.e. [Cross-platform command line script (e.g. .bat and .sh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966924/cross-platform-command-line-script-e-g-bat-and-sh)

example:

```
:; someLinuxCommand.sh
:; exit
windowsCommandHere.cmd
```

[Single script to run in both Windows batch and Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510688/single-script-to-run-in-both-windows-batch-and-linux-bash)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have no experience in using powershell scripts unfortunately, a just some experience in using pre and post build events. How do I use this in my pre-build event?

Comment: create a ps1 script and execute it - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500320/post-build-event-execute-powershell

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but unfortunately does not solve my problem. Project must build in app center and it does not support powershell :(. Anyway for me to do this using bash?